# Приложения с "тяжелой" графикой Android SDK

Tags: android-sdk, android, bitmap

Есть "тяжелая" графика, нужно сделать приложение на Android SDK с этой графикой. Если ее засовывать в ImageView или как фон кнопок, то будет `OutOfMemoryException` . Можно как то адаптировать графику? Если использовать BitMap, то со временем не вылезет эта же ошибка?

P.S. тяжелая графика значит высокого разрешения

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно использовать `Bitmap`, то все отработает правильно - без `OutOfMemoryException`.

Надо просто не создавать `Bitmap` бездумно, а совпадающий с характеристиками устройства (т.н. Device Dependent Bitmap).

Почитайте [подробную статью](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

В любой момент рантайма работающего графического приложения у программиста **есть возможность** использовать не более `WIDTH*HEIGHT` байт памяти, отведенных на графику. Это действительно так и не нужно быть суперумным, чтобы понять почему. Хотя, на деле все оказывается несколько труднее..

Вот, например, ваше приложение. Несмотря на наличие встроенного в Java `Garbage Collector`а`, вы умудряетесь израсходовать всю отведенную для процесса память. Это говорит о том, что где-то в архитектуре вашего графического приложения есть "щели", через которые память и утекает.

**Заводите и освобождайте графические сущности по мере необходимости.** Если ваша графика рисуется с `FPS=60`, следует, например, задуматься: а действительно ли нужна такая скорость? Может и 30 кадров в секунду вполне хватит? ( учитывая характер рисуемой графики и свойство человеческого мозга воспринимать не более 24 кадров в секунду ). Графика - это очень обширная тема, далеко выходящая за пределы графических библиотек и программирования  в целом.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно подгружать и выгружать картинки по мере необходимости. Вот тут полезная ссылка с официального сайта [android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Уменьшите разрешение, для кнопок full hd  явно излишне, да и для фона .... хотя иногда приходится, не совсем верное, откровенно говоря костыльное решение просто порезать фоновоую  картинку на части и загружать по очереди (сетка в фтошопе )